# Unable to dispatch multiple domain events via MediatR entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mediatr

I have a status in one of my entities whereby if the status is cancelled or completed then I want to dispatch an event which is sent via MediatR. If the status is payment successful, I want to send an email and then proceed with the cancelled / completed event.

The entity looks like this:

```
public Order : BaseEntity
{
   ....

   private OrderStatus _status = OrderStatus.InProgress;

   public OrderStatus Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set
        {
            if (SentAt != null)
            {
                // Already done the workflow, no longer need to do them.
                _status = value;
                return;
            }

            if (value is OrderStatus.Cancelled or OrderStatus.Completed)
            {
                AddDomainEvent(new SendOrderStatusUpdate(this));
            }

            if (value == OrderStatus.PaymentSuccessful)
            {
                AddDomainEvent(new SendInvoice(this));
            }

            _status = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this. If I set the order status as `OrderStatus.PaymentSuccessful` it runs through the event for that and at the end I set the status to `OrderStatus.Completed` it does not run the domain event correlating to that status.

My `BaseEntity` class is relatively the same as the recommended approach for this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier for the entity.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// The domain events.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<BaseEvent> _domainEvents = new();
    
    [NotMapped]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();
    
    public void AddDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }
    
    public void RemoveDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Remove(domainEvent);
    }
    
    public void ClearDomainEvents()
    {
        _domainEvents.Clear();
    }
}
```

I then extend MediatR to work with Hangfire in order to queue the events and do them in the background, again the recommended approach.

```
public static class MediatorExtensions
{
    public static async Task DispatchDomainEvents(this IMediator mediator, DbContext context)
    {
        var entities = context.ChangeTracker
            .Entries<BaseEntity>()
            .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
            .Select(e => e.Entity);

        var domainEvents = entities.SelectMany(e => e.DomainEvents).ToList();

        entities.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ClearDomainEvents());

        foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
        {
            var client = new BackgroundJobClient();

            client.Enqueue<MediatorBridge>(bridge => bridge.Publish(domainEvent));
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the secondary domain event to fire, however, it doesn't seem like it is getting in there.

I originally thought that the `ClearDomainEvents` method may be getting confused and clearing the domain events before it's fired. I have confirmed that this is not the case and it appears as though the event is "dispatching" but the MediatR `INotificationHandler<SendOrderStatusUpdate>` is not getting within.

Setting the order status as `OrderStatus.Completed` immediately triggers that workflow correctly so I feel like it's something to do with the running order and how they are handled.

UPDATE:

I have since got this working, however not completely.

I have updated the dispatch to be the following:

```
public static async Task DispatchDomainEvents(this IMediator mediator, DbContext context)
{
    var entities = GetEntitiesWithPendingEvents(context);

    while (entities.Any())
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        foreach (var domainEvent in entity.DomainEvents.ToList())
        {
            var client = new BackgroundJobClient();
            client.Enqueue<MediatorBridge>(bridge => bridge.Publish(domainEvent));
            entity.RemoveDomainEvent(domainEvent);
        }

        entities = GetEntitiesWithPendingEvents(context);
    }
}

private static List<BaseEntity> GetEntitiesWithPendingEvents(DbContext context)
{
    return context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<BaseEntity>()
        .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
        .Select(e => e.Entity)
        .ToList();
}
```

Which picks up the update as it is triggered within another event handler. However, this works when calling it immediately i.e: `_mediator.Publish(domainEvent)` but not in my current setup whereby I am trying to pass it through Hangfire. It doesn't seem to get picked up.